# elastic search watcher license

Tags: elasticsearch, licensing, elasticsearch-watcher

I have an elastic cluster of 20 nodes, and am planning on setting up a separate monitoring cluster with watcher of 2 nodes.
When I request for a license (Gold subscription) for watcher, will it be enough if I get licenses for just the monitoring cluster of 2 nodes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a license for the cluster that is hosting those plugins that require a license: Shield, Watcher, Marvel.

So, in your case you should be fine to have Watcher on that two-node cluster with a license for that cluster.